# How to calculate specific percentages

Tags: r, data.table, percentage

I have a data table in which data is given at 4 different levels (level 0, 1, 2 and 3). I want to calculate how supply in level 3 is distributed in level 2 for each state. (I have kept `occ_code` in table so that even if `state_code` and `level` are same, it is a unique record)

Creating sample Table:

```
library(data.table)
state_code = c(rep(1,14))
level = c(0,1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,3)
occ_code = LETTERS[1:14]
supply = c(100,60,50,25,25,10,10,40,30,10,10,10,10,10)    
DT = data.table(state_code,occ_code,level,supply)
```

Desired output

```
perc = c(NA,NA,NA,0.5,0.5,NA,1,NA,NA,0.33,0.33,0.33,NA,1)
DT2 = data.table(DT,perc)
```

Basically, I want to use these percentages to project another data which is given only at level 2.

Comment: The calculation is not clear

Comment: ok, context for the calculations is- supply in level n is sum of supply in level n+1. for example total supply is 100  (level 0) which is divided into (60 and 40 for level 1), supply in level 1 - is further divided into level 2 and then supply in level 2 is further divided into level 3.

Comment: That would make sense, but your example does not conform to that description. For state code 1, the total by level is 100, then 60, then 50, then 50.

Comment: @Frank, it is because level 0 is sum of level 1 (you can't count level 2 here, it will cause double counting)

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it now. The meaningless state code column threw me off. Interesting way to store tree-structured data (if I'm reading it right).

Comment: @Frank, my sincere apologies, I did a mistake in creating the sample data. State code should always be 1 here. (I kept two state codes to show that there are multiple states, however, then I created data for only 1 state and not 2 different states). I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
DT[, rl := rleid(level), by = state_code
   ][level == 3, perc := supply/sum(supply), by = .(state_code, rl)
     ][, rl := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DT
>     state_code occ_code level supply      perc
>  1:          1        A     0    100        NA
>  2:          1        B     1     60        NA
>  3:          1        C     2     50        NA
>  4:          1        D     3     25 0.5000000
>  5:          1        E     3     25 0.5000000
>  6:          1        F     2     10        NA
>  7:          1        G     3     10 1.0000000
>  8:          2        H     1     40        NA
>  9:          2        I     2     30        NA
> 10:          2        J     3     10 0.3333333
> 11:          2        K     3     10 0.3333333
> 12:          2        L     3     10 0.3333333
> 13:          2        M     2     10        NA
> 14:          2        N     3     10 1.0000000
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Restructuring the data to store information for only level 3.  The other information can be calculated from this:

```
library(data.table)
dt3 <- DT[level == 3, ]
dt3[, parent := c("2C", "2C", "2F", "2I", "2I", "2I", "2M")]
dt3[, perc := round(supply / sum(supply), 4), by = parent]

   state_code occ_code level supply parent   perc
1:          1        D     3     25     2C 0.5000
2:          1        E     3     25     2C 0.5000
3:          1        G     3     10     2F 1.0000
4:          2        J     3     10     2I 0.3333
5:          2        K     3     10     2I 0.3333
6:          2        L     3     10     2I 0.3333
7:          2        N     3     10     2M 1.0000
```

Calculating the `supply` for `level` 0, 1, and 2 respectively:

```
dt3[, sum(supply)]
dt3[, sum(supply), by = state_code]
dt3[, sum(supply), by = parent]
```

A second approach:

```
DT[level == 2, parent := paste0(level, occ_code)]
DT[level > 1, parent := parent[1], by = .(cumsum(!is.na(parent)))]
DT[level == 3, perc := round(supply / sum(supply), 4), by = parent]

    state_code occ_code level supply parent   perc
 1:          1        A     0    100     NA     NA
 2:          1        B     1     60     NA     NA
 3:          1        C     2     50     2C     NA
 4:          1        D     3     25     2C 0.5000
 5:          1        E     3     25     2C 0.5000
 6:          1        F     2     10     2F     NA
 7:          1        G     3     10     2F 1.0000
 8:          2        H     1     40     NA     NA
 9:          2        I     2     30     2I     NA
10:          2        J     3     10     2I 0.3333
11:          2        K     3     10     2I 0.3333
12:          2        L     3     10     2I 0.3333
13:          2        M     2     10     2M     NA
14:          2        N     3     10     2M 1.0000
```

Comment: What is the down vote for?  Is the goal to provide a complex answer that involves grouping by the `level` and data order (row number)?  There is redundant information stored in the provided data set and this is an alternative approach that simplifies things and does not remove any data.

Comment: not my downvote, but your initial answer relied on hardcoded levels which doesn't scale very well

Comment: @manotheshark, Thanks for the answer! Would it be possible for you to explain this code `DT[level > 1, parent := parent[1], by = .(cumsum(!is.na(parent)))]`works

Comment: @GauravSinghal it will increment each time there is non-`NA` value which is used to copy the `level` 2 `parent` value to the associated `level` 3 rows.  This will show how it works:  `cumsum(!is.na(c(NA, "a", NA, NA, 4, NA)))`

Comment: Thanks @manotheshark, though I have accepted Jaap's answer, your answer  actually helps me in the next step as well !!!